# swift 5 custom cell image click

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I've been trying for 3 hours what I did not run. I couldn't find the reason.

> Why doesn't the prin function work?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
    img.image = UIImage(named: "Heart-icon")
    img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let gesture = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(prin(tapGesture:)))
    img.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    cell.addSubview(img)
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

@objc func prin(tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("çalıştı")
}
```

Comment: Try with this :
```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("çalıştı")
}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have multiple interactions inside the cell go with `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Otherwise i would use the delegate method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` since you have detection in the whole cell which is usually helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Because you implement Custome TableviewCell (Cell.swift)

Just Add in ViewDidLoad()

```
self.tableView.register(Cell.self)
```